# .htaccess redirect from domain.org/sub to sub.domain.org/ not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get aphdigital.org/GVH/ to redirect to gvh.aphdigital.org, and aphdigital.org/GVH/something/ to gvh.aphdigital.org/something/ but I'm having quite a lot of difficulty. I tried the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127176/create-a-301-redirect-in-htaccess-for-folder-to-subdomain-and-redirect-www-to-n), but it's not working. The commented-out code blocks below also show failed attempts at a redirect. What am I doing wrong? I would enable logging if I had access to httpd.conf, but I only have FTP access. I know apache is reading this file, because syntax errors seem to cause 500 errors.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
# Remember to enable display_errors on development environments only.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value display_errors 1
    php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

# If know that mod_rewrite is enabled, but you are still getting mod_rewrite errors,
# uncomment the line below and replace "/" with your base directory.
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [C]
RewriteRule .* admin/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php

# Added this on Jan. 4, 2013 to redirect from old URL to new. Doesn't seem to be working. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.aphdigital.org/GVH$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.aphdigital\.org/GVH$
RewriteRule ^gvh/(.*)$ http://gvh.aphdigital.org/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
# End of Jan. 4 add.

#TEST for redirect added April 3. Also doesn't work. 
# To redirect /mysub/foo to http://mysub.mysite.co.uk/foo
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(aphdigital\.org)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(gvh)/?(.*)$ http://$1.%2/$2 [R=301,L,NC] 

#TEST2, code from Stackoverflow question 
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /

# To redirect http:://www.mysite.co.uk/ to http:://mysite.co.uk/
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(aphdigital\.org)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# To redirect /mysub/foo to http://mysub.mysite.co.uk/foo
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(aphdigital\.org)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(gvh)/?(.*)$ http://$1.%2/$2 [R=301,L,NC] 
#END TEST 2

#Intentionally breaking to see if reading .htaccess. Yep, this breaks it. 
#<directory / ></directory> 

<FilesMatch "\.(php|ini)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files index.php>
Allow from all
</Files>

# Uncomment the lines below in order to enable caching of some files via Apache (after a finished site has gone live)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#  <FilesMatch "\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$">
#       ExpiresActive on
#       ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 day"
#   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

This is for a site running the Omeka CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL path `GVH` is not part of `%{HTTP_HOST}`, so this should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?aphdigital\.org$
RewriteRule ^gvh/(.*)$ http://gvh.aphdigital.org/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.